# HashMap.KeySet() returns keys in different order in Java 7 Java 8

Tags: java

```
public class TestClass {    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String,Integer> testMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        testMap.put("Key1", 1);
        testMap.put("Key2", 2);
        testMap.put("Key3", 3);
        testMap.put("Key4", 4);
        testMap.put("Key5", 5);
        //[Key2, Key1, Key4, Key3, Key5] //java7
        //[Key2, Key1, Key5, Key4, Key3] //java8
        System.out.println(testMap.keySet().toString());
    }

}
```

Why there is difference in the order of the keys?

Comment: Actually, the order of elements in a set (like the keySet) is undefined and can be anything. If you need a specific order, use a SortedMap or sort the keys before using them. The change of Java version might lead to using a different sized array for holding the values inside a HashMap (just a guess).

Comment: Sets are unordered

Comment: Number of times you run your program and get keyset you find a difference most of the times. So there is no difference in java 7 or java 8 keyset code.

Comment: @Imran - Actually, that is incorrect for that program.  For any given Java platform, that program will always return the keys in the say order.  Why?  Because the hashcode value for a given `String` is specified, and the behaviour of a HashMap is determinate.

Comment: If you need the keys ordered as they are inserted use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: Why would you ever expect them to be the same in an unordered Map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why there is difference in the order of the keys ?

Because:

1. the Java specs (i.e. the javadocs) do not specify the order of a HashMap's keyset, and
2. there were major changes to the implementation of HashMap between Java 7 and Java 8.

Those implementation changes (which gave significant performance improvements) resulted in the order of the keyset changing.

But that is not considered a "breaking" change because the keyset order has always been clearly noted as *unspecified* .... meaning that you should not rely on it.

Comment: major changes are related to ...?

Comment: @AndrewsBAnthony the data is stored differently and thus would be iterated differently.  You would have to read and compare the source to find every change which might impact the order.

Comment: Related to performance .... like I said.  Actually, one of the things is that hash chains beyond a certain length may be converted into binary trees.  See the Java 8 source code for details.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering is not guaranteed as per spec. Individual VM's are free to implement whatever they choose.

Comment: @JFMeier If it's valuable you'd better turn it into an answer.

Comment: Actually collections are written in Java, so VM has nothing to do with the collection elements order.

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap does not maintain order, if you want ordered insertion you can use linkedhashmap :)

Answer (score 0):

Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.